# what is a good way to connect to elastic beanstalk in boto when programmatically setting a region?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I'm using boto (http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/) and would like to programmatically choose a region when connecting to elastic beanstalk.  So far, all I have been able to come up with is:

```
import boto
from boto.beanstalk.layer1 import Layer1
Layer1.DefaultRegionName = 'us-west-1'
Layer1.DefaultRegionEndpoint = 'elasticbeanstalk.us-west-1.amazonaws.com'
ebs = boto.connect_beanstalk()
```

While I can in theory call

```
boto.connect_beanstalk(region=<something>)
```

I cannot figure how to construct a boto.regioninfo.RegionInfo, which is apparently what the Layer1 class expects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That definitely looks like a bug to me - but looking closer at the code it appears that the connection parameter on the RegionInfo is never used. Setting it to None when constructing your own RegionInfo and then passing it into the constructor seems to work for me.

```
regionInfo = boto.regioninfo.RegionInfo(None, 'us-west-1', 'elasticbeanstalk.us-west-1.amazonaws.com')
beanstalk = boto.connect_beanstalk(region=regionInfo)
mt.describe_applications()
```

For what it's worth I'm pretty sure only the full region endpoint parameter is used when making a connection - e.g. "elasticbeanstalk.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"

Comment: Much better than what I was doing!

Answer (score 0):

The way I have been doing this is using `connect_to_region`, like so:

```
import boto
ebs = boto.beanstalk.connect_to_region('us-west-1')
```

This will take care of properly initializing (and caching) the needed `RegionInfo` objects.